# $G$ is bipartite iff $\chi(G)=2$

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification, coloring, bipartite-graphs

If $G$ is a loop-free undirected graph with at least one edge, prove that $G$ is bipartite if and only if $\chi(G)=2.$

***Definition 11.18** A graph $G=(V,E)$ is called bipartite if $V=V_1 \cup V_2$ with $V_1 \cap V_2 = \emptyset$, and every edge of $G$ is of the form $\{a,b\}$ with $a\in V_1$ and $b\in V_2$.*

I start by supposing $G$ is bipartite, coloring the vertices in $V_1$ $\color{blue}{blue}$ and the vertices in $V_2$ $\color{red}{red}$, then by definition of bipartite, every edge $\{a,b\}$ has vertices of different colors. $\chi(G)=2$.

Next, if $\chi(G)=2$, then if $\{a,b\}\in G$, then $a$ and $b$ are colored with different colors, and since $\chi(G)=2$ there are only two colors. There is no edge where both vertices are of the same color. You can write $V=V_1 \cup V_2$ where $V_1$ is all the vertices of color $1$, $V_2$ of color $2$. $V_1 \cap V_2 = \emptyset$ because no vertex is colored twice, and every edge is of the form $\{a,b\}$ where $a \in V_1$ and $b \in V_2$. Thus $G$ is bipartite.

Apparently I was supposed to make use of the fact that there was at least one edge?

Comment: @bof why not make this an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no edges, then we have the empty graph on $n$ vertices (which only requires one color) or the null graph (the graph on no vertices, which has chromatic number $0$).

A graph $G$ with at least one edge is bipartite iff $\chi(G) = 2$. In general, a graph $G$ is bipartite iff $\chi(G) \leq 2$.

Note that in the definition of a bipartite graph, there is no stipulation that $V_{1}, V_{2}$ are non-empty.

Comment: thank you for this great answer, but I’m having trouble making the the leap and spotting the error in my proof

Comment: Your proof misses cases where the chromatic number is less than 2- namely, the empty and null graphs. The forward direction of your proof is only true when the graph has an edge.